# How do I access a dictionary value for use with the urllib module in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7, key, urllib

Example - I have the following dictionary...

```
URLDict = {'OTX2':'http://lsdb.hgu.mrc.ac.uk/variants.php?select_db=OTX2&action=view_all',
'RAB3GAP':'http://lsdb.hgu.mrc.ac.uk/variants.php?select_db=RAB3GAP1&action=view_all',
'SOX2':'http://lsdb.hgu.mrc.ac.uk/variants.php?select_db=SOX2&action=view_all',
'STRA6':'http://lsdb.hgu.mrc.ac.uk/variants.php?select_db=STRA6&action=view_all',
'MLYCD':'http://lsdb.hgu.mrc.ac.uk/variants.php?select_db=MLYCD&action=view_all'}
```

I would like to use urllib to call each url in a for loop, how can this be done?

I have successfully done this with with the urls in a list format like this...

```
OTX2 = 'http://lsdb.hgu.mrc.ac.uk/variants.php?select_db=OTX2&action=view_all'
RAB3GAP = 'http://lsdb.hgu.mrc.ac.uk/variants.php?select_db=RAB3GAP1&action=view_all'
SOX2 = 'http://lsdb.hgu.mrc.ac.uk/variants.php?select_db=SOX2&action=view_all'
STRA6 = 'http://lsdb.hgu.mrc.ac.uk/variants.php?select_db=STRA6&action=view_all'
MLYCD = 'http://lsdb.hgu.mrc.ac.uk/variants.php?select_db=MLYCD&action=view_all'

URLList = [OTX2,RAB3GAP,SOX2,STRA6,PAX6,MLYCD]

for URL in URLList:                                                        
    sourcepage = urllib.urlopen(URL)                                     
    sourcetext = sourcepage.read()
```

but I want to also be able to print the key later when returning data. Using a list format the key would be a variable and thus not able to access it for printing, I would lonly be able to print the value.

Thanks for any help.

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about it like this:

```
for url_key in URLDict:
    URL = URLDict[url_key]

    sourcepage = urllib.urlopen(URL)
    sourcetext = sourcepage.read()
```

The url is obviously `URLDict[url_key]` and you can retain the `key` value within the name `url_key`. For exemple:

```
print url_key
```

On the first iteration will print`OTX2`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried (as a simple example):

```
for key, value in URLDict.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't look like a dictionary is even necessary.

```
dbs = ['OTX2', 'RAB3GAP', 'SOX2', 'STRA6', 'PAX6', 'MLYCD']
urlbase = 'http://lsdb.hgu.mrc.ac.uk/variants.php?select_db=%s&action=view_all'

for db in dbs:
    sourcepage = urllib.urlopen(urlbase % db)
    sourcetext = sourcepage.read()
```

Comment: Good spot! +1 - I'd personally use `urllib.urlencode` to do the parameters though... (Short of using `requests`)

Comment: Thanks that is nifty, I should have shown there was greater variety in the URLs though, those were just a quick subset, there will be hundreds of others where substitution can not be used

Comment: @TomSmith: But, maybe many of them are similar. You could use a set of URL patterns to reduce duplication (and make it easier to change if the URL formats change, as they are wont to do).

Comment: @nneonneo: indeed, it is definitely useful and shall be called upon at certain points. cheers